# check to see if then load external scripts if they arent present

Tags: javascript

I have 3 external files that have to be loaded for my adverts to display

```
 http://www.manx.net/Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js?v=12.01.2012
 http://www.manx.net/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js?v=12.01.2012
 https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js
```

Problem is, if i have 2 of our adverts running at the same time on the adserver they conflict as they are both trying to pull the external files in at the same time. (i have to include these files in my advert each time as the adserver randomly picks the adverts to display).

Is there a way that i can scan to see if the files are already loaded on the page, if they are do nothing and run the rest of the file. If they arent loaded then load and run the rest of the file that follows.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check whether the script is loaded or not like this :

```
var getLength = $('script[src*="**filename**"]').length; 

if (getLength == 0){
    //then script not loaded, so run the script here

    $.getScript(**filename**);
}
```

Hope it works for you :)

Comment: <script> 
var getLength = $('script[src*="http://www.manx.net/Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js?v=12.01.2012"]').length; 

if (getLength == 0){
    //then script not loaded, so run the script here

    $.getScript('http://www.manx.net/Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js?v=12.01.2012');
}
</script>

Comment: Sorry pressed enter with out writing anything. Above is what i setup in my file but the advert doesnt run at all now